# New Wordpress media uploader tool, featured images, and plugin interactions

Tags: wordpress

The new Wordpress media uploader tool introduced in 3.5 causes problems with a few plugins, including a fairly massive one I developed.

The problem manifests like this:

> 1. New media uploader installed as part of upgrade to 3.5
> 2. No longer possible to add/save a featured image

Disabling Plugin X fixes the problem.

My problem is that, while I know that Plugin X causes the problem, no errors are thrown in PHP or JavaScript, so I don't know where the issue is arising to fix the plugin.

I read elsewhere (ref lost) that it is caused by a conflict with plugins that use JQuery ... but the comment did not say specifically which JQuery actions conflict with the featured image.

I do notice that the Wordpress Ajax URL returns an empty JSON object when my plugin is enabled. When I disable the plugin, a JSON object with properties of the uploaded image is returned.

Any ideas?

Comment: With the new media uploader, many functions related to uploading and storing images in WP core were rewritten and/or deprecated in favor of new functions/classes for media management.  Sorry I can't be more specific - don't have time to research, but I recall reading this recently when working with similar stuff.  Consult the codex.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in the plugin listening for Ajax calls in the wp-admin area, and interfering with the Ajax calls being made by the featured image tool. Preventing the plugin for listening for Ajax calls in the wp-admin area solved the problem.